# Index of normal subgroup in a normal series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with $H,K$ subgroups. Suppose that there is a series of normal subgroups:
$$
G \ \trianglerighteq G_1 \ \trianglerighteq G_2 \ \trianglerighteq \dots \ \trianglerighteq G_r = H.
$$

How can I prove that $(H:H\cap K)$ divides $(G:K)$? I've tried to use some very common identities, but nothing works, because I can't write $(G:H)$.

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
After some digging, I think I was able to answer the question. Well, is true that
$$
(G:H \cap K) = (G:H)(H:H\cap K)
$$
and
$$
(G:H \cap K) = (G:K)(K:H\cap K).
$$
So,
$$
(G:H)(H:H\cap K) = (G:K)(K:H\cap K) \implies \frac{(G:H)}{(K:H\cap K)}(H:H\cap K)=(G:K).
$$
But, since $H$ is normal in $G$, we have $$\frac{(G:H)}{(K:H\cap K)} = \frac{\frac{|G|}{|H|}}{\frac{|K|}{|H\cap K|}} = \frac{|G|}{\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}} = \frac{|G|}{|HK|} = (G:HK) \in \Bbb{N}. $$

So, $(H:H\cap K)$ divides $(G:K)$.

Comment: Why can't you write $(G:H)$?

Comment: @Randall Can I? I don't know if there is enough information. But I've made some progress: The question resumes to prove that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$. Ok, $H$ is normal, so $HK$ is subgroup.

Comment: The index is defined for any subgroup, not just the normal ones.

Comment: $(H:H\cap K)$ divides the order of $H$ (because $(A:B)|B|=|A|$, where $A,B$ are groups, $B$ is a subgroup of $A$ and $|B|$ is the order of $B$), which divides $G$

Comment: @Randall I've edited my post, with a try. Could you please take a look?

Comment: @Randall and yes, I know it is defined, but the problem was when I look to the division of index, to write something that is suitable.

Comment: In your solution, you have written "since $H$ is normal in $G$", but you have not assumed that $H$ is normal in $G$, only that it is subnormal.

Comment: @DerekHolt That's true, thanks! So, there is another way to do this? I was thinking in the theorem of correspondence, but I don't know if it works here.

Comment: By induction on the length $r$ of the subnormal series, $(H:H \cap K)$ divides $(G_1:G_1 \cap K)$, but $(G_1:G_1 \cap K) = (G_1K : K)$ which divides $(G:K)$, because $G_1K$ is a subgroup of $G$.